# SQl T-Sql Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named 'OJDT'. There is a column in that table named 'TransType'.  There are codes of different transaction types in that column. On each Transaction Type, There are also different tables. objective is that i take 'TransType' from 'OJDT', and depending upon 'TransType' go to the respective table and fetch 'DocNum' and 'Comments' from that table. 'OJDT' and each 'TransType' can be joined via 'TransId'. And one unique condition is when 'TransType' is 30, then fetch 'DocNum' and 'Comments' from 'OJDT'. There is no need to go in external table for that purpose to fetch these records. I use CASE Statement on each trans type and fetch the record but the problem is an error occured syaing 'subquery returns more than one value'. It should occur because i'm using it (this case query as a whole) in another query.

```
select case ojdt.transtype
when 46 then
(select docnum from OVPM    --OVPM is the respective column of code 46
inner join OJDT
on ojdt.transID = ovpm.Transid
)
```

similarly i've used all the cases but error occurs & it should.
What Should i Do??

Comment: select top 1 docnum from OVPM

Comment: there seem to be more than one docnum in ovpm that have the same transid. do you want to see all of them or just the oldest/newest?

Comment: I want to see all of them

Comment: There should be more than 1 docnum as multiple transactions has occurred. There are also transID according to each trnsaction and each transid can also have multiple transactions

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be as follows

```
select (case 
when ojdt.transtype=46 then
(select docnum from OVPM    --OVPM is the respective column of code 46
inner join OJDT
on ojdt.transID = ovpm.Transid
) else '' end) [Trans Type]
```

Answer (score 0):

this query will give you all the docnums from ovpm that fit the transid:

```
select case when transtype = 46 then ovpm.docnum
            when transtype = 30 then ojdt.docnum
       end as docnum
  from ojdt
  left outer join 
       ovpm
    on ojdt.transid = ovpm.transid
   and ojdt.transtype = 46
```

Comment: but when i sue that query inside another query, error occurs.

Comment: i can't help you with that unless you show me the other query that you put this one into. the error message would help, too

Comment: select secondSet.[Transaction Date], secondSet.Location , ThirdSet.[Voucher Number] ,secondSet.[Document Type] , FourthSet.Description, FirstSet.[Vendor Name], FirstSet.Amount, FirstSet.[Activity Code]
from
(
select RefDate, TransId,Credit as [Amount], AccntntCod as [Activity Code], case jdt1.ShortName
when '_SYS%' then '  '
else 
(select CardName from OCRD where CardCode = JDT1.ShortName)
end as [Vendor Name]
from JDT1
inner join OACT
on JDT1.Account = OACT.AcctCode
where Credit != 0.000000  
) as FirstSet

Comment: inner join
(
select RefDate as [Transaction Date] ,TransId, Name as [Location], case ojdt.transtype
when 46 then 'Outgoing Payments'
when 20 then 'Goods Receipt PO'
when 18 then 'A/P Invoice'
when 19 then 'A/P Credit Memo'
when 21 then 'Goods Return'
when 67 then 'Inventory Transferes'
when 60 then 'Goods Issue'
when 30 then 'Journal Entry'
when 24 then 'Incoming Payments'
when 59 then 'Goods Receipt'
when 310000001 then 'Inventory Opening Balances'
end as [Document Type]
  from OJDT
inner join OUSR
on OJDT.UserSign = OUSR.USERID
inner join OUBR
on ousr.Branch = OUBR.Code
) as secondSet

Comment: on secondSet.TransId = FirstSet.TransId
inner join
(
select ojdt.TransId,ojdt.TransType,case ojdt.TransType
when 60 then 
(select DocNum from OIGE where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 46 then 
(select DocNum from OVPM where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 20 then 
(select DocNum from OPDN where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 18 then 
(select DocNum from OPCH where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 19 then 
(select DocNum from ORPC where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 21 then 
(select DocNum from ORPD where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 59 then 
(select DocNum from OIGN where TransId = ojdt.TransId)

Comment: when 24 then 
(select DocNum from ORCT  where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 67 then 
(select DocNum from OWTR  where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 310000001 then 
(select DocNum from OIQI  where DocNum = ojdt.Ref1)
when 30 then
(select ojdt.Number where TransType = 30)
end as [Voucher Number]
 from OJDT
) as ThirdSet
on FirstSet.TransId = ThirdSet.TransId

Comment: inner join
(
select ojdt.TransId, ojdt.TransType, case ojdt.TransType
when 60 then 
(select Comments from OIGE where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 46 then 
(select Comments from OVPM where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 20 then 
(select Comments from OPDN where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 18 then 
(select Comments from OPCH where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 19 then 
(select Comments from ORPC where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 21 then 
(select Comments from ORPD where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 59 then 
(select Comments from OIGN where TransId = ojdt.TransId)

Comment: when 24 then 
(select Comments from ORCT  where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 67 then 
(select Comments from OWTR  where TransId = ojdt.TransId)
when 310000001 then 
(select Comments from OIQI  where DocNum = ojdt.Ref1)
when 30 then
(select top 1 LineMemo from JDT1 where jdt1.TransId = (OJDT.TransId) AND jdt1.Credit != 0.000000) 
 end as [Description]
 from OJDT
) as FourthSet
on FirstSet.TransId = FourthSet.TransId
order by FirstSet.[Activity Code]

Comment: it is the whole query @Brett Schneider

Comment: it shows the error in the last comment. when 30 then it shows multiple result and i want to show all of them.I have used top 1 because if i not use it , then it shows the error that subquery returns more than one result. this is not permitted in case of =, =>, < , <= e.t.c.

Comment: @SaadHamid i thought you might put all that as an edit into your question. i looked at your sql and the problem remains in the description and voucher numbers. you cannot have `when 60 then (select...` return more than one row, because in the surrounding select you are at row level. in order to have more than one row you should use a join construct as i have outlined in my answer